# Point QuickSight to s3 Bucket with sevral subdirectories in it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-quicksight

How can I Point QuickSight to the entire bucket it has many folder and many CSV's in the sub directories, Can QuickSight recursively pick all CSV's ?

```
{
    "fileLocations": [
        {
            "URIs": [
                "https://bucet_name.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "globalUploadSettings": {
        "format": "CSV",
        "delimiter": ",",
        "textqualifier": "\"",
        "containsHeader": "true"
    }
}
```

But when I point to specific CSV ,QuickSight Picked it Up

```
{
    "fileLocations": [
        {
            "URIs": [
                "https://bucet_name.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/2020/04/23/09/abc.csv"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "globalUploadSettings": {
        "format": "CSV",
        "delimiter": ",",
        "textqualifier": "\"",
        "containsHeader": "true"
    }
}
```

ScreenShot of error Attached:

---

[Error scrrenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CectQ.png)

Answer (score 1):

I changed "URIs" with "URIPrefixes" because  URI is used to specify the absolute path of the file in the S3 bucket and hence manifest file will not work for the values containing path of the bucket or prefix.

```
{
    "fileLocations": [
        {
            "URIPrefixes": [
                "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/<bucket_name>"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "globalUploadSettings": {
        "format": "CSV",
        "delimiter": ",",
        "textqualifier": "\"",
        "containsHeader": "true"
    }
}
```

Reference:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/supported-manifest-file-format.html#quicksight-manifest-file-format